# Http links from Paperclip with s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip with s3_permissions = :private

I have some assets of the same model that are public and I want to generate a HTTP link for them (not HTTPS)

for generating the url I'm currently using my_model.my_asset.expiring_url(1000)

how can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure the `s3_protocol` to be HTTP (it defaults to HTTPS when `s3_permissions` are not `public_read`):

```
# config/application.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_protocol: 'http',
  s3_permissions: :private,
  s3_credentials: { ... }
}
```

That said, if you set the protocol to HTTP, you will be potentially exposing the assets anyway. HTTPS would be preferable if you care about privacy of the assets.

You can read more about the available options [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3).